# collect datatable all rows data, which is having input and select (updated data) fileds

Tags: jquery, datatable

For collecting all rows data, I'm calling below code and it's works fine.

```
var table = $('#exampleTable').DataTable();
var data = table.rows().data();
```

But, I want collect updated data, which I can update in input and selected fields in row cells, as shown in below link. In result i'm getting old data.

The data is showing in below table, I'm loading dynamically.

Code link : https://jsfiddle.net/phLtk2mh/107/

Comment: I would save all changes one by one as soon as a value changes. You will need the database `id` for that line somewhere.

Comment: Is there any other way collect data-table data, apart from table.rows().data(), which I get new enter data(all at once)  in input fields.

Comment: With `table.rows().data()`, you get the data in an object formed so DataTable can understand it. So you can manipulate it and call `draw()` to redraw the table. That is not the right way to update a database... Where you will need the database line `id` number to `UPDATE`. You have to do it using something like `$("input").on(change",function(){...})` then do an Ajax request to update the database with the new value on the right line.

Comment: So look for Ajax and try to manage the request to update using some SQL. Your question, as it is now, is too broad.

Comment: Yes Patrice, I'm using ajax for sending my request. And I want collect datatable data in form of JSON array. Backend was Java Spring, Hibernate and Mysql is DB.

Comment: Datatable does not know about the changes made in the inputs. The data you collect are taken from its object. The user changes are not in this data. You HAVE to use an `.on("change", function(){...}` somewhere to send the new values using Ajax... And even just to change the DataTable object before a `draw()`... Anyway.

Comment: In short, changing an input value does not change the datable's data in the object it uses to draw. That's why you only have the "old" values.